# dividing sum of the column with each part

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i have the following table in my database 
i am currently using oracle 11g

the data is like this

```
id   valus 
1    2     3
100 200  300   = 600
```

I want to derive new column as: divide each value from the column "value" with the total sum of the column "value". Then load into the another table. The data in other table should look as

```
id value drived_col
1   100    100/600
2    200    200/600
3    300    300/600
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/df8539/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE data ( id, value ) AS
          SELECT 1, 100 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 200 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 300 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE derived_data AS
SELECT id,
       value,
       value/SUM(value) OVER ( ORDER BY NULL ) AS derived_col
FROM   data;
```

Or if the `derived_data` table already exists then you can do:

```
INSERT INTO derived_data
SELECT id,
       value,
       value/SUM(value) OVER ( ORDER BY NULL ) AS derived_col
FROM   data;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM derived_data
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/df8539/1/0)**:

```
| ID | VALUE |    DERIVED_COL |
|----|-------|----------------|
|  1 |   100 | 0.166666666667 |
|  2 |   200 | 0.333333333333 |
|  3 |   300 |            0.5 |
```

**Or if you want the `derived_col` as a string:**

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b3ace/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE data ( id, value ) AS
 SELECT 1, 100 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 200 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 300 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE derived_data AS
SELECT id,
 value,
 value||'/'||SUM(value) OVER ( ORDER BY NULL ) AS derived_col
FROM data;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM derived_data
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b3ace/1/0)**:

```
| ID | VALUE | DERIVED_COL |
|----|-------|-------------|
|  1 |   100 |     100/600 |
|  2 |   200 |     200/600 |
|  3 |   300 |     300/600 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table already exists, you want to use an `INSERT INTO new_table SELECT` to insert the data in the derived table based on a query.  For the insertion query to perform the division, it needs two subqueries:

1. query the sum of the values
2. query the (id,value) pair

Because the sum of the values is a single value, constant for all rows, you can then join these subqueries together with an INNER JOIN that has no conditions:

```
INSERT INTO derived_table
SELECT
  ot.id    AS id,
  ot.value AS value,
  CAST(ot.value AS float)/summed.total AS derived_col
FROM
  orig_table AS ot
INNER JOIN 
  SELECT sum(value) AS total FROM orig_table AS summed;
```

The `CAST(ot.value AS FLOAT)` is necessary if `value` is a column of integers.  Otherwise, your division will be integer division and all of the derived values will be zero.

There is no join condition here because the summation is a single value to all rows of `orig_table`.  If you want to apply different divisors to different rows, you would need a more complicated subquery and an appropriate join condition.